# How to add SharePoint spell checker on "Publishing Content" field?

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I have a specific requirement of showing SharePoint OOTB spell check error message, shown in below image, in page layout for "Publishing Content" field which is type of Publishing HTML.

[image]

How can I implement this?

Note: "Publishing Content" is SharePoint OOTB field added in content type by default when content type is inherited from Welcome Page.

Comment: What do you mean by showing spell checked? When checkin the page the spell check option is available I guess in the pop up by default. What else do you want?

Comment: I want to show SharePoint OOTB spell check message. I have updated my original question with image. Please check.